Is there a way to detect a HomeButton Press for Versions up of Tiramisu
I'm currently creating a custom home launcher and i have sub pages (for example the app drawer), if i want to leave from there back the the main home screen (on most launchers different pages), the most intuitive way of doing so is the home button. How do I detect the user pressing this?
(!) I don't want to override it's behaviour, I want to detect the press of it.
I tried using the IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS), but it's deprecated (and therefor I'm reluctant to work with it).
I tried using the registerReceiver(this.homeButtonPressed, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN), RECEIVER_EXPORTED) even with the Receiver_Exported, but no luck there, it didn't trigger the listerner, no matter what i did (also Catergories.HOME didn't work).
What I tried and what doesn't work (cause this is the homescreen) is to use the onPause, this wont trigger, cause the homescreen activity doesn't pause on home button press.
